# Number of ways to choose two disjoint subsets of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements. Then, in how many ways, can we choose an ordered pair $(B,C)$, where $B,C$ are disjoint subsets of $A$?

Let A={1}, then B can be {phi} and C can be {1}. So, one ordered pair.

Let A={1,2}, then B can be {phi}, {1} and C can be {1},{2}. So three ordered pairs.

Let A={1,2,3}. Then B can be {phi},{1},{2} and C can be {1},{2},{3}.

So six pairs ? Am I going in the right direction ?

Comment: $A=B\cup C\cup (A-(B\cup C))$

Answer (score 7):

Your question means that you need to find the number of ways an ordered pair $(B,C)$ can be selected such that $B$ and $C$ are subsets and $B  \cap C=\emptyset$.

To do so we can reduce this problem into another simpler one. Let each element of $A$(which has say $n$ elements) represent a different ball. So now you have $n$ balls.

Let's take two boxes $B$ and $C$ and a rubbish chute $R$(which will be of use when you don't want the element/ball in any of the set/box).

Now each of the $n$ balls can go into either $B$, $C$ or $R$. Which implies that each of the $n$ ball can be used in three ways.

It means that the number of ways of using the balls is $3^n$. The balls in $B$ and $C$ represent the different elements of subsets.

Therefore if we have a set $A$ with $n$ elements, there would exist $3^n$ ordered pair of disjoint subsets $(B,C)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Each element of $A$ is either in $B$, in $C$ or in neither. Hence, how many disjoint subsets pairs are there?

Comment: Let A={1}, then B can be {phi} and C can be {1}. So, one ordered pair.
Let A={1,2}, then B can be {phi}, {1} and C can be {1},{2}.
So three ordered pairs.
Let A={1,2,3}. Then B can be {phi},{1},{2} and C can be {1},{2},{3}. So six pairs ? Am I going in the right direction ?

Comment: @user47252 No. Try and apply the Rule of product.